# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Android

Tags: android, xmpp, noclassdeffounderror

I was integrating XMPP in my project, it was working fine but it crashed some of the device like Moto G... Below i mentioned crash report

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.xmpp.MyXMPP$MMessageListener
                                                                at 
com.app.xmpp.MyXMPP.init(MyXMPP.java:88)
                                                                at 
com.app.xmpp.MyXMPP.<init>(MyXMPP.java:57)
                                                                 at 
 com.app.xmpp.MyXMPP.getInstance(MyXMPP.java:63)
                                                                 at 
com.app.xmpp.XmppService.onCreate(XmppService.java:54)
                                                                 at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2791)
                                                                at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                at 
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
                                                                 at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at 
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                 at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at 

  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                    at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Help me out how to solve this issue.

Comment: how much is your method count ?

Comment: Go to `Build` - `Analyze Apk` and check if you crossing dex limit. If so you might need to add support to multidex.

Comment: multiDexEnabled true i already put on my gradle @NileshDeokar

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection;  i got this exception @NileshDeokar